the Window API documentation doesn't show keydown as an eventlistener but it works
I've been following a tutorial in which the following line was written :
    window.addEventListener('keydown',dosomething())


I went to official window api documentation and looked through the list of available events but keydown was not present in there.
so an event listener that isn't listed in the documentation is working; am I missing something or is the documentation out of date ? and if yes, where can one find the full list of available event listeners that can be used ?

See the keyboard events on the same website:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

From the Element: keydown event documentation: If no suitable element is in focus, the event target will be the <body> or the root.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You are looking at documentation on windows events. The keydown event is not there becaue it occurs on an element which is in focus at the time (e.g. input) . Note that while MDN is usually a reliable source it is not the 'official' documentation.

Note also that when you put:  window.addEventListener('keydown',dosomething()) assuming dosomething is the name of the function you want to perform when the key goes down then remove the (), otherwise the function gets performed immediately.

That's because the event bubbles up to the Document, which has a special get the parent algorithm returning its global object (i.e. the Window object). So all bubbling events (but load) will also go through the window, even though they're not fired on it directly.
